# Please help me calculate this sum

Tags: summation

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\sum_{j=1}^{p}\left[\frac{1}{\frac{1}{p-\alpha(j-1)}(1-\frac{1}{p-\alpha(j-1)})^{p-j}} \cdot\frac{1}{(\theta-\frac{1}{p-\alpha(j-1)})(p-j+1)}\right] \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$p$ is a finite constant, $\theta$ is a constant between 0 to 1, $\alpha$ is a constant making $\theta-\frac{1}{p-\alpha(j-1)}$ bigger than 0.

Please help me calculate this sum, or find the upper and lower bound(especially the upper bound).

Thank you very much!

Comment: Seems as though the question would be far more readable is $p_{n}N$ were just written as a single character, say $p$, since it is simply a constant? Also, it is an integer, yes?  In addition to being finite.

Comment: yes, it is a constant, an integer and finite. Thank you.

Comment: $\sum_{j=1}^{p}\left[\frac{1}{\frac{1}{p-\alpha(j-1)}(1-\frac{1}{p-\alpha(j-1)})^{p-j}} \cdot\frac{1}{(\theta-\frac{1}{p-\alpha(j-1)})(p-j+1)}\right]$